# skimage.measure.block_reduce with lambda function

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing, lambda, scikit-image

I have an array:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randint(0,10,size=[8,8])
```

`arr` is:

```
array([[9, 1, 8, 2, 0, 4],
       [0, 7, 6, 9, 7, 5],
       [0, 7, 1, 6, 6, 2],
       [3, 6, 3, 3, 8, 1]])
```

I want to reduce the size of this array using [`skimage.measure.block_reduce`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.block_reduce). I do

```
from skimage import measure as sm
reduced_arr = sm.block_reduce(arr, block_size=(4,6), func=np.max)
```

`reduced_arr` is:

```
array([[6, 7],
       [9, 7]])
```

I try to achieve the same thing using a lambda function:

```
reduced_arr = sm.block_reduce(arr, block_size=(2,4), func= lambda block: np.max(block))
```

Then I get an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-115-a11dc12d3db0> in <module>()
----> 1 reduced_arr = sm.block_reduce(arr, block_size=(2,4), func= lambda block: np.max(block))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/skimage/measure/block.py in block_reduce(image, block_size, func, cval, func_kwargs)
     85 
     86     return func(blocked, axis=tuple(range(image.ndim, blocked.ndim)),
---> 87                 **func_kwargs)

TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

**How to use `block_reduce` with lambda functions?**

My real world use case is more complicated than just a premade numpy function, that is why I need it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this question still need an answer, but I saw another one, so let's give a try.

Following the doc of skimage, it's specified the function given in argument should ["implement an axis parameter"](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.block_reduce). Quickly looking for `np.mean` in the numpy doc and you see that indeed it [implements an axis parameter](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html).

Therefore in the source of block reduce itself, axis parameter is called on `func` :

```py
def block_reduce(image, block_size=2, func=np.sum, cval=0, func_kwargs=None):
      ...
      return func(blocked, axis=tuple(range(image.ndim, blocked.ndim)),
                         **func_kwargs)
```

That being said, your custom function should then implement such behaviour. With a quick fix, your example will correctly work now :

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randint(0,10,size=[8,8])
arr
Out[53]: 
array([[3, 3, 2, 8, 0, 4, 2, 6],
       [8, 9, 8, 5, 1, 6, 1, 0],
       [9, 2, 6, 9, 7, 9, 1, 6],
       [3, 6, 8, 2, 8, 2, 1, 3],
       [8, 0, 3, 3, 9, 6, 5, 4],
       [5, 2, 9, 3, 8, 5, 9, 8],
       [2, 9, 0, 7, 0, 0, 5, 8],
       [6, 4, 7, 1, 9, 9, 6, 9]])

from skimage import measure as sm
reduced_arr = sm.block_reduce(arr, block_size=(4,6), func=np.max)
reduced_arr
Out[55]: 
array([[9, 6],
       [9, 9]])

reduced_arr_with_lambda = sm.block_reduce(arr, block_size=(4,6), 
                                          func= lambda block, axis: np.max(block, axis))
reduced_arr_with_lambda
Out[57]: 
array([[9, 6],
       [9, 9]])

np.testing.assert_array_equal(reduced_arr, reduced_arr_with_lambda)
```

Finally, for a more spicy function, you need to understand how tuple axis work, and for non-numpy function implement a way to use axis. To be honest, it's tedious, so my advice is to stick with numpy function.